# iPhone - build a cell to look like this

Tags: iphone, ios

Hey guys, I want to build a `UITableView` cell to look something like this that is used in the new vBulletin iPhone app. Here is a picture. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: According to me there are two ways to create cell like this in table view just create a cell and insert it on table view or just divide it

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might be able to do it [Using Cell Objects in Predefined Styles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW11), according to the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW15). Just add a UILabel as a subview to the cell's content view to get that extra line of text with different styling. Then, you may also have to add a UIImageView of the subview of that UILabel to show the message bubble image.

Also, check out the section [Programmatically Adding Subviews to a Cell’s Content View](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW15).

That's exactly how I customized the appearance of the table view cells for a [chat view for acani](https://github.com/acani/acani-iphone/blob/master/Lovers/Classes/ChatViewController.m#L429).

Best,

Matt

Comment: Thanks mat your help is highly appreciated im new to this site so im thankful for any help

Comment: hey matt i have another question are those green post bubbles accessory views? if not what are they and how do you would you implement them to display the number of posts like they have